# Laravel: Email verfication link while registering redirects to login page, even if there is no such logic

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have created the authentication scaffolding from laravel. I have overwritten a few of the methods from the traits, but none of them have a logic that will redirect to the login page when clicking on the verification link sent to mail for users.
laravel version: 10.18.0

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});

Route::get('login/google', [LoginController::class, 'redirectToGoogle'])->name('login.google');
Route::get('login/google/callback', [LoginController::class, 'handleGoogleCallback']);

Route::post('password/reset', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'reset'])->name('password.update');

// Resend the email verification link
Route::get('/email/resend', function (Request $request) {
    $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return back()->with('message', 'Verification link sent!');
})->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])->name('verification.send');
```

**RegisterController**

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'date_of_birth' => ['nullable', 'date'],
        'phone_number' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:20'],
    ]);
}


protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'date_of_birth' => $data['date_of_birth'],
        'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
        'role' => 'customer',
        'is_active' => true,
    ]);
}

   // Override the method to handle the registration process
   public function register(Request $request)
   {
       $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

       if ($validator->fails()) {
           $this->throwValidationException(
               $request, $validator
           );
       }

       $user = $this->create($request->all());

       event(new Registered($user));

       return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'You have been successfully registered.');
   }

}
```

Other than these, I have not overwritten any custom methods related to registering.

Currently, what it does is whenever I register through the app, a user will be created in DB with the email_verified_at column as null. A mail is sent with the verification link. When I click on the link or copy-paste it, it redirects me to the login page, and the column in DB is also not updated with the timestamp.

Comment: your email.resend route has auth Middleware. If I want to resend my email verification link, I'm not logged in, right? Then why do I need that auth middleware?

Comment: even if I remove that middleware it still redirects to login

Comment: @gauravmaharjan where is the route that handle the verification link, something like `Route::get('email/verify', ...` ?

Comment: @HichemTech, wouldnt this route  Auth::routes(['verify' => true]) handle everything related to authentication ?

Comment: If you run `php artisan route:list` in the terminal do all the related routes show up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` the email verification is handled by the laravel default handler which redirect to the login page after.

to solve this you can use your own route/controller instead of `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`:

```
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', CustomEmailVerificationController::class)
    ->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])
    ->name('verification.verify');
```

###### CustomEmailVerificationController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;

class CustomEmailVerificationController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(EmailVerificationRequest $request)
    {
        $request->fulfill();

        // customize the redirection page
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```